# Top cell name changes when changing any cell name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `HabitViewController` `(UITableViewController)` with a button to add cells. When a cell is added its default title is "New Habit". Then the user can tap the cell and a detailViewController appears with a picker to choose the habit. The cell.label.text is then set to the selected option in the picker. This is where my problem is. For example, if i added 3 cells by pressing the button three times, then selected the third row. And then I chose the option Hello World. The top cell would be named hello world, not the third cell. Is this normal? Here is my code:

## HabitViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewDelegate> {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellNameSender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedCell;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "HabitViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *myCells;    
}
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellName2;


@end

@implementation HabitViewController

@synthesize cellNameSender, selectedCell;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.editButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1]];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    addButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!myCells) {
        myCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [myCells insertObject:@"New Habit" atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myCells.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = myCells[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [myCells removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.delegate = self;
}
#pragma mark - DetailViewDelegate

-(void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    [myCells replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:cellName];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

## DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DetailViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName;
@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *PickerData;    
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *habitField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar *toolBar;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DetailViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *backButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *Picker;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *PickerData;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *barDoneButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customHabit;

- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "HabitViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController () {
}

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize PickerData, Picker, toolBar, backButton, barDoneButton, flexSpace;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerData = @[@"Posture",@"Paludies Abbs",@"Custom"];

    [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];

    [toolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_navigation_bar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:nil];
// Done button on toolbar
    barDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(releasePicker)];
// Back button on toolbar

    backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(backToPicker)];

// Habit PickerView

    Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Picker.delegate = self;
    barDoneButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

// Toolbar above picker

    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];

    self.habitField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.habitField addTarget:self action:@selector(customHabitChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];

}
- (void)customHabitChanged {
    self.customHabit = self.habitField.text;
    self.cellName = self.customHabit;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.customHabit);
    [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];
}
- (void)backToPicker {
    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];
    [self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (void)releasePicker {
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];
    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [PickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [PickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self.delegate setCellName2:self.PickerData[row]];

 /*   int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {
        self.cellName = @"Posture";

        self.habitField.text = @"Posture";

        [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

        NSLog(@"%@ Is Selected", self.cellName);
    }
    if (select == 1) {

        self.cellName = @"Palaudies Abbs";

        self.habitField.text = @"Palaudies Abbs";

        [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

        NSLog(@"%@ Is Selected", self.cellName);
    }
    if (select == 2) {

        [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.habitField setInputView:nil];
        [self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];

        [toolBar setItems:@[backButton, flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];

        self.habitField.text = @"";

        self.habitField.placeholder = @"Custom";

        [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

        NSLog(@"%@ Is Selected", self.cellName);


  */  //}
}
```

Comment: Of course they're all going to be the same because that's what you're telling it to do. You set the label text with cell.textLabel.text = @"New Habit";. That will set every cell's label to that. You need to have a data source (an array) and use the indexPath.row passed in to access different items in the array. I suggest you read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: Ok, thanks ill read it

Comment: So Im guessing I will have to set the name of the selected tableViewCell, not just cellName. can you give me some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(indexPath.row == object.count-1)
  cell.textLabel.text = @"New Habit";
else
{
   NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

}

    return cell;
```

Comment: I think I follow you, can you see if my updated answer is correct? Becuase now its not changing the label at all

Comment: I think a problem is updating the tableView, after the view appears.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking on this is not right. You shouldn't think in terms of setting the title of a cell, but instead think about updating the array that you use to populate the table view with data. Here is a simplified version of your app. When you click the add button it adds a new cell in row 0 with the label's text being "New Habit". When you click on that cell (or any other), it takes you to the controller with the picker view where you choose a string, and that string is passed back to the table view in a delegate method. In that method I update the array, myCells with that passed in string at the correct index gotten from the table's indexPathForSelectedRow, and then call reloadData on the table view to update it's view.

This is the table view controller:

```
#import "TableController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myCells;
@end

@implementation TableController 

- (IBAction)insertNewObject:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (!self.myCells) {
        self.myCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.myCells insertObject:@"New Habit" atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.myCells.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.myCells[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.delegate = self;
}

-(void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    [self.myCells replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:cellName];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is the controller (ViewController) with the picker view:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *pickerData;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pickerData = @[@"Posture",@"Paludies Abbs",@"Custom"];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self.delegate setCellName2:self.pickerData[row]];
}
```

Comment: The app now crashes when the add button is tapped.

Comment: Would you like me to change the code in the question to the current one?

Comment: @user2660874, yes, it would be useful to see what you're doing now.

Comment: @user2660874, I don't see anything in that code that would cause it to crash  when you touch the add button. First, you should try commenting out everything inside the insertNewObject: method (and maybe add a log to see if it's called), and see if it still crashes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35656/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user2660874)