# How to set the selected row of a tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and I add cells with a button on the UIViewController.

If the cells are tapped, you are brought to a new `viewController` which has a picker.

How can I set the the selected cell's text as title for next viewController?

Comment: i can not understand your question//

Comment: Sorry, What is the method to set the title of a selected tableViewCell?

Comment: you want to set the title of the header ?

Comment: post some code please...

Comment: I answered the other question that you posted tonight (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284718/top-cell-name-changes-when-changing-any-cell-name/18285571#18285571), and that should answer this one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF YOU WANT TO SEND SELECTED ROW's TITLE TO NEXT VIEW CONTROLLER (push)
```

1. Create property (say title) in your new view controller's .h file to hold title of selected row and synthesize title property in your new view controller's .m file.
2. update `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

   ```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 


    {
    YourNewViewController *vc= [[YourNewViewController          
    alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourNewViewControllerNIB" bundle:nil];

    vc.title=[[titleArray objectAtIndexPath]indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }
   ```
3. now you have selected row's title in your new view controller.
4. for setting this title as navigation bar title
   write this code to `viewDidLoad` of your new view controller.

   self.navigationItem.title=title.

IF YOU WANT TO SEND SELECTED ROW's TITLE TO PREVIOUS VIEW CONTROLLER (POP)

for this you have to use delegate pattern and you have to make custom protocols.

follow this. -
  [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

// This is how to get selected cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Some title";
```

Comment: I updated the question to make more sense

Answer (score 2):

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *NewTitle = @"Add your new title here";
```

Comment: I cant test right now, but should I be able to set the title of just the cell that im in the view controller ofr?

Comment: I updated the question to make more sense

Comment: You want to pop back to the view and the particular cell should have the title u selected from the picker in the next view ?

Comment: That is exactly right

Comment: @user2660874- then you need to create custom protocol > :0

Comment: Then simply create a global string like NSString *GlobalString in lets say your Appdelegate.h .... Then simply inherit the class in both the views and assign your picker value to the GlobalString and same in your previous view .....

Answer (score 2):

Write this code in either **button's** method ***OR*** your **picker's** method

```
      UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
      cell.textLabel.text = self.MyButtonName.titleLabel.text;
      [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I updated the question to make more sense

Comment: @user2660874- check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629449/how-to-create-and-use-protocol-if-more-then-one-class-implements/15629532#15629532

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the selected row?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Your Title"];
    [_tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: I think cell.text isn't right ....

Comment: @nabeel, I updated the question to make more sense