# How to pass data back to the original UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ios7

[image: StoryBoard]

I would like to pass some data from the last Table View to the First View. How can I do grab a hold of the First View object? I'm familiar with delegate pattern. 
From the First View, I'm using Style Modal to invoke the Table View.

Comment: do you also use `segue` ? and have to tried to use the `delegate` pattern ?

Comment: The delegate pattern would not be implemented by `grab a hold of the First View object`. The source object would set itself as the delegate during the presentation of the destination object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285182/how-to-set-the-selected-row-of-a-tableview/18285649#18285649

Answer (score 1):

Create an object to manage your data model outside of your controller structure (singleton or owned by the application delegate).  Update it when you have new data and read from it when you want to display something.  Then, instead of having to make links between controllers, all you need to do is remove the one or ones you don't want and let the one you go back to decide what to show.

Comment: I prefer not to use Singleton. What's the application delegate?

Comment: If you chose a standard project type when you started your app, one was created for you.  The actual name will be `AppDelegate` or something more complicated if you specified a class prefix.  You can retrieve it with code like `AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`.

Answer (score 0):

to get your rootViewController of your navigation controller, you can try this

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
YourRootViewController *rootViewController = (YourRootViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
```

and add your data to rootViewController

Comment: We try to access rootViewController and above code gives me rootViewController